# gsub R extracting string

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am trying to extract a string between two commas with gsub. If I have the following

```
xz<- "1620 Honeylocust Drive, 60210 IL, USA"
```

and I want to extract everything between the two commas, (`60120 IL`), is it possible to use gsub?

I have tried

```
gsub(".*,","",xz)
```

The result is USA. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

We can match zero or more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]*`) followed by a `,` followed by zero or more space from the start (`^`) of the string or `|` a `,`  followed by zero or more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]*`) at the end (`$`) of string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^,]*,\\s*|,[^,]*$", "", xz)
#[1] "60210 IL"
```

Or another option is using `sub` and capture as a group

```
sub("^[^,]+,\\s+([^,]+).*", "\\1", xz)
#[1] "60210 IL"
```

---

Or another option is `regexpr/regmatches`

```
regmatches(xz, regexpr("(?<=,\\s)[^,]*(?=,)", xz, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "60210 IL"
```

---

Or with `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(xz, "(?<=,\\s)[^,]*(?=,)")
#[1] "60210 IL"
```

#### Update

With the new string,

```
xz1 <- "1620, Honeylocust Drive, 60210 IL, USA"
sub(".*,\\s+(+[0-9]+[^,]+).*", "\\1", xz1)
#[1] "60210 IL"
```

Comment: thank you very much, and if the string is `1620, Honeylocust Drive, 60210 IL, USA`?

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis  Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using strsplit and grep (here I did it in 2 lines for readability):

```
xz1 <- "1620, Honeylocust Drive, 60210 IL, USA"
a1 <- strsplit(xz1, "[ ]*,[ ]*")[[1]]
grep("^[0-9]+[ ]+[A-Z]+", a1, value=TRUE)
#[1] "60210 IL"
```

It's not using gsub, and in the present case it is not better, but maybe it is easier to adapt to other situations.